# События мыши. Не знаю почему но мой код на JS не работает

Tags: javascript

Не знаю почему но мой код на JS не работает. При нажатие на `<i class="itemAdd">тут должно быть фото корзины</i>` должен срабатывать следующий код на js
`

```
let balance = 0;
[...document.querySelectorAll(".itemAdd")].map(item => {
  return item.addEventListener("click", event => {
    let sum = document.querySelector(".item_price").textContent;
    sum = parseInt(sum.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""), 10);
    balance = balance + sum;
    console.log("balance= " + balance);
  });
});`
```

Но в итоге нечего не работает?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let balance = 0;
[...document.querySelectorAll(".itemAdd")].forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", event => {
    let sum = document.querySelector(".item_price").textContent;
    sum = parseInt(sum.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""), 10);
    balance = balance + sum;
    console.log("balance = " + balance);
  });
});
```

```html
<i class="itemAdd">тут должно быть фото корзины</i>
<br/>
<span class="item_price">123 rubles</span>
<br/>
```